# fstab not mounting partitions automatically

Tags: boot, filesystem, mount, fstab

When I create new partitions on the flash drive I'm finding that they are not being mounted at boot. Here is my fstab:

```
devpts                 /dev/pts      devpts    defaults            0      0
shm                    /dev/shm      tmpfs     nodev,nosuid        0      0
/dev/mmcblk0p1         /boot         vfat    defaults              0      0
/dev/mmcb1k0p4         /home         ext4    defaults              0      0
```

The new partition, `/home` does not get mounted.

Also, interestingly it fails to mount with:

```
$ sudo mount /home/
mount: special device /dev/mmcb1k0p4 does not exist
```

But this mounts fine:

`sudo mount /dev/mmcb1k0p4 /home`

Comment: This question can be closed as it turns out it's very localized.

Comment: You should close this @Jivings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unbelievable, there is a typo here:

```
/dev/mmcblk0p1         /boot         vfat    defaults              0      0
/dev/mmcb1k0p4         /home         ext4    defaults              0      0
         ^
```

It should be an `l` not a `1`.